# Find items in list 1 that are also found in list 2

Tags: python

I am trying to find elements from list1 that also match list2.

What I've done so far:

```
    with open('C:\python\list1.txt') as f:
    firstList = f.read().splitlines()

with open('C:\python\list2.txt') as g:
    secondList = g.read().splitlines()

resListFound = []
resListNotFound = []

for x in firstList:
    if x in secondList:
        resListFound.append(x)
        print (x + " found in list 2!")
    else:
        print (x + " NOT found in list 2")

    resListNotFound.append(x)


resultFile1 = open('found.txt', 'w')
resultFile2 = open('notFound.txt', 'w')

for item in resListFound:
    resultFile.write("%s\n" % item)
for item in resListNotFound:
    resultFile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

The problem is that I am getting `OSErrror(22, 'Invalid Argument)` on line 4 but I don;t see anything that could trigger this as it's loading the `list2` file just as the `list1`

Comment: Is your white space/tabbing correct? Python is sensitive to white spacing and tabbing.

Comment: can you add your full error traceback to the question please?

Comment: My guess is `'C:\python\list2.txt'` isn't your real path to the second file. `OSErrror(22, 'Invalid Argument)` can happen when you have characters your OS doesn't allow in the file path, such as `'C:\folder\thefilename.txt'` which contains a tab character `\t`. To turn off string escaping prepend an `r` like so and the path becomes valid `r'C:\folder\thefilename.txt'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to maintain the order, you could use a set for a faster comparison:

```
with open('C:\python\list1.txt') as f:
    firstSet = set(f)

with open('C:\python\list2.txt') as g:
    secondSet = set(g)

resListFound = firstSet & secondSet
resListNotFound = firstSet - secondSet
```

If you do need ordering, then you can convert just the second list to a set for faster lookup:

```
secondSet = set(secondList)

for x in firstList:
    if x in secondSet:
        resListFound.append(x)
        print (x + " found in list 2!")
    else:
        resListNotFound.append(x)
        print (x + " NOT found in list 2")
```